# What is the difference between these two domonad maybe-m statements?

Tags: clojure, monads

The following two statements give the same result:

```
(with-monad maybe-m
  (domonad [a nil
           b (+ 1 a)]
    b)) ;; nil

(domonad maybe-m [a nil
          b (+ 1 a)]
  b) ;; nil
```

I'm still very new to clojure and especially monads, but I was just trying to figure out what the difference is in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [with-monad](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads/blob/90909e30965bb59fccc8e527d31f8aaabc9d404b/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/monads.clj#L161), you'll see that all it does is extract the meaningful functions out of the monad given as the first argument.

[domonad](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads/blob/90909e30965bb59fccc8e527d31f8aaabc9d404b/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/monads.clj#L173) is a "syntactic suger" to let you write monadic operations without manually binding and returning. it actually uses with-monad internally to evaluate the exprs using the monads meaningful functions.

if you call domonad with only two parameters, as you did in your first example, it assumes you are already in a context of a monad, meaning that all the meaningful functions are available. in your first example, they are indeed available because you made them available by using with-monad before the call. OTOH, if you call it with three arguments, as in your second example, it first introduces the context of the monad using with-monad, and then proceeds to evaluate the binding.

So in essence, these two samples are exactly the same.